# Place scene object to get behind UI element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in my scene's sky and want to prevent it from getting cut out of the view, no matter the screen ratio. So I set up a canvas and a *PlaceHolder* `RectTransform` on it, that - as being UI element - gets scaled and repositioned in respect to the screen aspect ratio. My goal is to use this position to determine where to put my scene object by using the following script:

```
Camera mainCam;
RectTransform placeHolder;
private void Start()
{
    mainCam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera")
        .GetComponent<Camera>();
    placeHolder = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SkyObjectPlaceholder")
        .GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    var screenPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(
        new Vector3(placeHolder.rect.x, placeHolder.rect.y, 0));
    transform.position = new Vector3(screenPos.x, screenPos.y,
         transform.position.z);
}
```

The issue is that my sky object is **always** placed in the center of the screen. It is not a child of anything on the scene, I just put it there. The placeholder is to the upper right in the canvas. Note that I tried playing with anchors for the UI element, set it to be left bottom, right top, no change, the scene object is always in the center of the screen.

What am I doing wrong? How to make a `Scene` element match up the position of a  `Canvas` element, so it gets right behind it?

**Note:** I'm using a perspective camera. I don't know if it matters, but I thought I mention it, just in case.

Yet another edit: after messing around with the issue a bit, I found that the problem is possibly linked to the `Z` input I give the `ScreenToWorldPoint`, in my case it's 0. I couldn't get a viable Z to input though.

Comment: Is easier to use Camera.main...

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... i think you should change the sorting layer of that object